# How to set tessedit_write_images in python-tesseract?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to set `tessedit_write_images` but can't seem to do it, i can't see the tessinput.tif anywhere

i'm doing:

```
import tesseract

api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
api.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY)
api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO_OSD)
api.SetVariable("tessedit_write_images", "T")
```

but i've tried with "True", "1", and some more variations, doesn't seem to work at all.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

`tessedit_write_images` is checked only once in Tesseract's source code (by `TessBaseAPI::ProcessPage()`, see [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/41478fd5a1f713f56ec51134d2598700b7f1463c/api/baseapi.cpp#L1224)).

So you have two ways:

1. Call `api.GetThresholdedImage()`, and the returned image is what will be saved if you set the variable and call `ProcessPage`.
2. Just call `api.ProcessPage()`, and it will see the variable and output the tif.

Comment: How do I set these parameters via mac terminal? I have downloaded Tesseract and am using it via command line, so when you say "you should call such and such method" I am not sure what you mean. How do I do that?

Comment: The important thing is that because of this hardcoded path "tessinput.tif" the tif file will be written to your **working directory** not regarding the `outputbase` command line option.