# Tesseract OCR Eye parameter "tessedit_write_images"

Tags: tesseract

Edit2: 
The config-file must have Unix Line Ending: Only "\n" and not "\r\n".

Edit: 
duplication [How to set tessedit_write_images in python-tesseract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560883/how-to-set-tessedit-write-images-in-python-tesseract)

Tesseract has an option to output the processed image, the so called Tesseract Eye. I use for first test the command line and I'm not able to get the output of the config parameter: tessedit_write_images

I have made a config file c:/tmp/config.txt with the only content:

```
tessedit_write_images true
```

Here's my command line:

```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR>tesseract c:/tmp/textscan11.tif     c:/tmp/textscan -psm 7  c:/tmp/config.txt
    Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.01 with Leptonica
    Page 1
```

I get c:/tmp/textscan.txt as output and that's all. The second file as result of the Eye-parameter is missing. I have searched the complete disk for the exspected file tessinput.tif.

-- Tesseract v3.05.01 Windows10 64 bit --

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check if c:/tmp/config.txt has expected line break (just '\n').

Comment: The \n newline dec 10 or 0x0A is there. See the file in hex:  74 65 73 73 65 64 69 74 5f 77 72 69 74 65 5f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 20 74 72 75 65 0d 0a

Comment: 0d 0a is windows EOL (\r\n) and it has to be just \n. You can use e.g. notepad++ for changin EOL to unix style.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Output file is in directory (Windows 10):  C:\Users\CarpeDiemKopi\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR                named tessinput.tif